How can I make this section-level Org-Mode header work at the top-level?
I find that the following org-mode header works just fine if I put it in a section
* SQL world
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sql: :exports both 
:header-args:sql+: :cmdline -S 123.45.0.6,1999 -U sa -P "AwfulPasswordManySpecialCharacters('(+\$kd'(+eQ" -C
:header-args:sql+: :engine mssql
:END:

but my every attempt to make it in to a session-level header, like this one in the documentation

#+PROPERTY: header-args:R  :session R

has resulted in syntax errors.
What is the correct syntax for making the above use #+PROPERTY?

You can just move the properties drawer as-is to the top of the file. I'll provide a reference later (tomorrow).

As I mentioned in a comment, you can move the whole PROPERTIES drawer as-is to the beginning of the file. You don't need to rewrite it using #PROPERTY keywords (although you can: see below):
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sql: :exports both 
:header-args:sql+: :cmdline -S 123.45.0.6,1999 -U sa -P "AwfulPasswordManySpecialCharacters('(+\$kd'(+eQ" -C
:header-args:sql+: :engine mssql
:END:

* SQL world


#+begin_src sql
select title from some_table;
#+end_src

You can check the environment of the code block by typing C-c C-v TAB on the code block. You will see a display like this:
Lang: sql
Properties:
    :header-args    nil
    :header-args:sql    nil
Header Arguments:
    :cache      no
    :cmdline    -S 123.45.0.6,1999 -U sa -P "AwfulPasswordManySpecialCharacters('(+\$kd'(+eQ" -C
    :engine     mssql
    :exports    both
    :hlines     no
    :noweb      no
    :results    replace
    :session    none
    :tangle     no

As you can see, the :exports, :engine and :cmdline arguments are set as specified in the PROPERTIES drawer at the top of the file.
That is completely general: any PROPERTIES drawer can be moved thus. You can imagine that there is an invisible Level 0 headline that is the parent of all the headlines in your file and the properties are inherited by every headline. See Property Syntax in the manual where it is stated that:
Properties can be inserted at the buffer level. That means they
apply before the first headline and can be inherited by all entries
in a file. Property blocks defined before the first headline must
be at the top of the buffer with only comments above them. 


If, instead, you want to use #PROPERTY keywords, you can, but you need to be careful with the colons. In a property drawer, some colons are part of the property syntax and some are not, so you need to keep the distinction in your head. For example, in the following PROPERTIES drawer:
:PROPERTIES:
:var:  foo
:var:x: :bar
:END:

the name of the first property is var and the value is foo. The colons surrounding the name of the property are part of property syntax. Applying this to the second property, the name of the property is var:x and the value is :bar - the colon in var:x is part of the property's name and the colon in :bar is part of the value - these colons are NOT part of the syntax of properties.
So in
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:sql: :exports both
...

the name of the property is header-args:sql and the value is :exports both.
Once you understand that, the rest is easy:
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql  :exports both
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :cmdline -S 123.45.0.6,1999 -U sa -P "AwfulPasswordManySpecialCharacters('(+\$kd'(+eQ" -C
#+PROPERTY: header-args:sql+ :engine mssql

* SQL world


#+begin_src sql
select title from some_table;
#+end_src

Checking with C-c C-v TAB should give you the same display as above.

Interesting. The first block doesn't work if it has #+LATEX_HEADER items beforehand. No wonder the docs say "Property blocks defined before the first headline must be at the top of the buffer with only comments above them.".
